# Selenium Headless Chrome Positions differ

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to get the positions of Web Elements in headless chrome mode. The Problem is, the y-positions of the Elements are always Different to the y-positions in non headless mode like +36 px on one Screen and +45 on another.

Can I setup Chrome headless so the Positions are the same like in non headless Mode?

Here are my Chrome Options:

```
options.addArguments("headless"); // mode
options.addArguments("disable-gpu");
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false); 
options.addArguments("disable-infobars"); // disabling infobars
```

Window size is set to Screen Resolution:

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
int width = (int)screenSize.getWidth();
int height = (int)screenSize.getHeight();
System.out.println("Width: " + width + " height: " + height);
driver.manage().window().setSize(new org.openqa.selenium.Dimension(width,height));
```